# Automated sorting of table after filter is selected

Tags: sorting, filter, tableau-api, data-analysis

```
timestamp     |     product      |      performance      |      sort_quantity
--------------|------------------|-----------------------|------------------------
2020-01-01    |     Product_A    |         high          |           819
2020-03-15    |     Product_A    |         high          |           819
2020-01-01    |     Product_B    |         low           |          -214
2020-03-15    |     Product_B    |         low           |          -214
2020-01-01    |     Product_C    |         high          |          -100
2020-03-15    |     Product_C    |         high          |          -100
2020-01-01    |     Product_D    |         low           |           933
2020-03-15    |     Product_D    |         low           |           933 
2020-01-01    |     Product_E    |         high          |           501
2020-03-15    |     Product_E    |         high          |           501
```

---

I insert the table above into `Tableau` looking like this: 
*(Sorry for only having it available in German)*

[image]

All this works perfectly.

---

Now I add a filter for column `performance` to the report. 
When I select one of the values in the filter (e.g. `high`) the report looks like this:

[image]

---

The filter function is correct but I also want that once the filter is clicked the table is **automatically sorted** (descending) based on column `sort_quantity`.

Is it possible to to do this with `Tableau`? 
If yes how can I achieve it?

Comment: applying a filter does not modify the (original) sorting of a table/chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a string version of sort quantity and place it as the first pill on rows, to the left of Product

```
str([sort quantity])
```

Set this field to sort Descending on by Field on Sort Quantity (not the str version).

[image]

On Str sort quantity, deselect show header to hide the column.

[image]

Final view should look like this.

[image]